# BundleContext is null in unit tests using pax-exam

Tags: java, osgi, pax-exam, pax

I'm using pax-exam to load, activate and access osgi bundles.

The following source code is my pax-exam test and it runs using pax-exam 2.3 using native container.

```
package fr.xlim.ssd.vtg.osgi;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.ops4j.pax.exam.Inject;
import org.ops4j.pax.exam.Option;
import org.ops4j.pax.exam.junit.Configuration;
import org.ops4j.pax.exam.junit.ExamReactorStrategy;
import org.ops4j.pax.exam.junit.JUnit4TestRunner;
import org.ops4j.pax.exam.spi.reactors.AllConfinedStagedReactorFactory;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.ops4j.pax.exam.CoreOptions.bundle;
import static org.ops4j.pax.exam.CoreOptions.junitBundles;
import static org.ops4j.pax.exam.CoreOptions.options;

@RunWith(JUnit4TestRunner.class)
@ExamReactorStrategy(AllConfinedStagedReactorFactory.class)
public class BasicOSGILoaderTest {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BasicOSGILoaderTest.class);

    @Inject
    private BundleContext bundleContext;

    @Configuration
    public Option[] config() {

    String projectRoot = null;

    try {
       projectRoot = ClassLoader.getSystemResource(".").toURI().toURL().toString();
       projectRoot = projectRoot.toString().substring(0,projectRoot.toString().length() - 27);
       logger.debug("project root: {}", projectRoot);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
       logger.error("malformed URL to project root: {}", projectRoot, e);
       throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
       logger.error("URI Syntax Error to project root: {}", projectRoot, e);
       throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }

    return options(
       junitBundles(),
       logProfile(),
       bundle(projectRoot + "libs/org.eclipse.ant.core_3.2.300.v20110511.jar"),
       bundle(projectRoot + "libs/org.eclipse.core.contenttype_3.4.100.v20110423-0524.jar"),
       bundle(projectRoot + "libs/org.eclipse.core.expressions_3.4.300.v20110228.jar"),
       bundle(projectRoot + "libs/org.eclipse.core.jobs_3.5.100.v20110404.jar"),
       bundle(projectRoot + "libs/org.eclipse.core.resources_3.7.100.v20110510-0712.jar"),
       bundle(projectRoot + "libs/org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.7.0.v20110110.jar"),
       bundle(projectRoot + "libs/org.eclipse.equinox.app_1.3.100.v20110321.jar"),
       bundle(projectRoot + "libs/org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.6.0.v20110523.jar"),
       bundle(projectRoot + "libs/org.eclipse.equinox.preferences_3.4.1.R37x_v20110725.jar"),
       bundle(projectRoot + "libs/org.eclipse.equinox.registry_3.5.101.R37x_v20110810-1611.jar"),
       bundle(projectRoot + "libs/org.eventb.core_2.4.0.r14093.jar"),
       bundle(projectRoot + "libs/org.eventb.core.ast_2.4.0.r14093.jar"),
       bundle(projectRoot + "libs/org.eventb.core.seqprover_2.4.0.r14093.jar"),
       bundle(projectRoot + "libs/org.rodinp.core_1.5.0.r14093.jar"),
       equinox().version("3.7.1")
     );
    }

    @Test
    public void checkBundleContext1() {
       assertNotNull(bundleContext);
    }

    @Test
    public void checkBundleContext2(BundleContext bc) {
       assertNotNull(bc);
    }

    @Test
    public void checkAccessToRodinDB() {
      RodinCore.getRodinDB();
    }
}
```

But I've the following problems:

- both checkBundleContext methods failed, bundle context injected (using `@Inject`) or passed as parameter of a test method are always null
- Access to the static method `getRodinDb()` from class `RodinCore` in bundle `org.rodinp.core_1.5.0.r14093.jar` throw a `ClassNotFoundException` about `org.rodinp.core.RodinCore`, even if the package `org.rodinp.core` is in Export-package of the bundle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check your import. Use

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
```

From [Service Injection page](http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/paxexam/Service+Injection) :

> Injection is indicated by a javax.inject.Inject annotation.  Pax
>   Exam's own Inject annotation of the 1.x release line is now
>   deprecated.

Comment: [link](http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/paxexam/Service+Injection)  Injection is indicated by a javax.inject.Inject annotation.

Comment: YEAH ! You've right: the right solution was to use `javax.inject.Inject`.

Answer (score 2):

check dependency:

```
<groupId>org.ops4j.pax.exam</groupId>
<artifactId>pax-exam-inject</artifactId>
```

it should be included during pax-exam tests.

more details [here](http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/paxexam/Service+Injection)

Comment: Added, but still not working: assertNotNull throws AssertionError with bundleContext annotates with `@Inject`

Comment: could you provide your POM also?